# pine scritp for loop strange outcome

Tags: loops, for-loop, pine-script, indicator, tradingview-api

I´m trying to create an acumulator by capital indicator, but don´t know why, doesn´t work properly.
I think is the for loop but can´t solve it.
The erros is that when I increase the % diference for the acummulating process, it makes stranges steps :

the code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © manolo_alm

study("ACUMULACIÓN", overlay = true)

//****************DEFINICIÓN DE VARIABLES**************************

vol_neg = 0.0 // función propia de TV pero lo renombramos
precio = 0.0 // precio medio de la vela high + low +center hlc3
//capital = vol_neg * precio// esto en principio sino lo resetamos puede calcular desde el origen de los tiempos o para cada vela
porcent_acu = input ( 0.1, title = "% precio altura banda AC" , step = 0.01)// variable para seleccionar la anchura óptima nos valdrá para estudiar cada producto
cap_neg_min = input (1, title ="M de Capital negociado ($)", step=500)// no olvidar multiplicar *10^6 
cap_neg_max = input (13300, title ="M de Capital negociado ($)", step=500)// no olvidar multiplicar *10^6
var acu_capital= 0.0 // va a ser un acumulador del capital negociado en un rango predefinido por sus condiciones de contorno de precio, decimal empieza en 0.0
var nvelas_acu = 0// número de velas en el rango de acumulación
inicio_acumulacion = input (defval=0, title="Velas inicio acumulación")
fin_acumulacion = input (defval=100, title="Velas máx acumulación")

//****************SET UP INICIAL**********************************
//
//****************ETIQUETAS************************************
// Crea las etiquetas para poder marcar los puntos tomados para generar las rectas

var etiq_cap = label.new(bar_index[0], high, text = "CAPITAL:" + tostring (acu_capital), style=label.style_square, textcolor=color.yellow, tooltip="Capital Negociado", size=size.normal )

//**************** PROGRAMA***************************************

//sólo debe acumular sí horizontalmente está en un rango de precios y a partir de un capital determinado no vale que lo etiquete si es poco importe
   

// ********************ACUMULADOR DE CAPITAL*****************************

// si la diferencia de altura de velas (por arriba o por abajo)  es < que la establecida por porcent_acu empieza a acumular

for i = inicio_acumulacion to fin_acumulacion// empezamos analizando grupos de 100 velas, ya vemos si hacen falta más vamos a ponerlo en una etiqueta el número
    if (high[i+1]/low[0]) < porcent_acu and (low[i+1]/low[0])< porcent_acu        
        capital = hlc3 [i] * volume[i]
        acu_capital := (acu_capital + capital)
        nvelas_acu := i

// Dibujar el etiqueta
label.set_x (etiq_cap, bar_index[nvelas_acu])
label.set_y (etiq_cap, high[nvelas_acu] )
label.set_text(etiq_cap, tostring (nvelas_acu) + "CAPITAL:" + tostring (acu_capital))
```

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This line's condition is almost never true so your loop isn't doing anything:

```
        if (high[i+1]/low[0]) < porcent_acu and (low[i+1]/low[0])< porcent_acu
```

The `high/low` ratio will typically revolve around 1, whereas your condition requires it to be < 0.1.